# Should I add the _TrackPageview Snippet to the <a> tag or somewhere in the JavaScript Container that fires when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to set up virtual pageviews for when a user clicks on buttons that are currently hosted in a lightbox.

I know that on a normal page, I just need to add the snippet in the `<a>` tag, but was wondering if the functionality is different inside a .js lightbox.

Do I need to add the snippet somewhere in the container or would I be okay with simply adding to the `<a>` tag for these links as well?

I will add the following:
I want to track clicks on the submit button at the base of this form:

http://www.teksystems.com/contact-us

I am confident that I can place the code in the `<a>` tag there.

But the two other links are hosted one on a side bar (accessible from any page) & the other in the lightbox that shows when you click "Send Us a Message"

Please tell me I can just add the snippet to the `<a>` tag on all of the links (because that is what I want to track is clicks). Thanks so much guys, here is what I have come up with if I can place these in the `<a>` tags:

`<a onclick="javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/header-thank-you/]);" href=”#”>Submit</a>`

`<a onclick="javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/virtual-contact/]);" target="_blank"><span class="link-text">Send us a message</span></a>`

`<a onclick="javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/header-thank-you/]);" href=”#”></a><span class="link-text">Submit</span></a>`

Here is an example of where I think a function code may go in the js container:

```
    `$(newButtonAnchor).click(function () {
        //alert('clicked');
        $(submitButton).click();
        return false;
    });

    var newButtonSpan = document.createElement('span');
    $(newButtonSpan).attr('class', 'text');
    $(newButtonSpan).html($(submitButton).val());`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to encapsulate all this_gaq stuff in to separate functions in a central lib. Otherwise you are likely facing a maintenance nightmare on the long run.

Besides: if you have an `onclick` parameter in your `<a` thus doesn't need `javascript:` as "protocoll", this *is* javascript: `<a onclick="_gaq.push...`

The jQuery aproach is the best from my point of view:

```
<style>
.gatracker {} /* does nothing but mark the elements */
</style>

<a target="_blank" href="go/some/where" class="gatracker"><span class="link-text">Send us a message</span></a>


   var ga_clickTracker = function(anchor) {
     ... some code ...
     _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $(anchor).attr('href')]);
     ...
   };


... onload ...

    // put an eventhandler on all elements with class gatracker
    $('.gatracker').click(function () {
        ga_clickTracker(this);
        return true; // should proceed!!
    });
```